# Deployment Failed: Deploy From Bitbucket Using AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I was able link bitbucket with aws although the deployment from bitbucket returns an error below.

```
Deployment Failed
The deployment failed because no IAM role with the IAM role name (arn:aws:iam::******:role/m30role) specified in this request was found. Make sure you are using the correct name of a service role that exists in your account. (Error code: IAM_ROLE_MISSING) Learn more
```

Any idea about this? Or which part of aws should I check

Any recommendation for a good tutorial on setting up Deploy From Bitbucket Using AWS CodeDeploy.

policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codedeploy:*",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

trust relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::****:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "connection:****"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Deployment configuration: CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime

---

Builds from bitbucket (Deploy to AWS) were uploaded to s3 buckets and I was able to see all the deployments history but then again all builds were failed.

Comment: Hi, make sure you have done every step correctly, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935468/auto-deploy-angular-4-app-using-bitbucket-pipeline-and-aws-codedeploy/50376850#50376850 I have listed the whole procedure in my answer there.

Comment: Is there a way where I can see log errors?   Currently deploy to aws returns this error: ->>>The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

Comment: check out the very last line in my answer. from code deploy application you can see the logs i think.